# Is it still not enough to simply use threads to update GUI?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, wxpython

For example:

```
class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        Initializing
        ...
        self.TextA = wx.StaticText(MainPanel, id = -1, label = "TextAOrWhatever")
        self.TextB = wx.StaticText(MainPanel, id = -1, label = "TextBOrWhatever")
        ...

    def StaticTextUpdating(self, ObjectName, Message):
        ObjectName.SetLabel(Message)

    def WorkerA(self):
        while True:
            Work on something

            UpdatingThread = threading.Thread(target = self.StaticTextUpdating, args = (self.TextA, "Something for TextA", ))
            UpdatingThread.start()

            time.sleep(randomSecs)

    def WorkerB(self):
        while True:
            Work on something

            UpdatingThread = threading.Thread(target = self.StaticTextUpdating, args = (self.TextB, "Something for TextB", ))
            UpdatingThread.start()

            time.sleep(randomSecs)

    ...

    def StartWorking(self):
        Spawn WorkerA thread
        Spawn WorkerB thread
        ...
```

As you can see, I always update `StaticText` in new threads, and I'm 100% sure at a whatever certain time point there's only one thread updating a specific object, but the problem is, every now and then after running for a while, some objects just disappear. Why is this happening? Does it mean GUI updating is not thread safe? Maybe only one object can be updated at a certain time point?

**Added:**

OK, wx.CallAfter should be a good solution for above codes. But I got another question, what if a button event and `SetLabel` happens at the same time? Wouldn't things like this cause troubles although I don't see any?

Comment: wx.CallAfter serializes the method call in the UI thread. Since events are dispatched in the UI thread they can't happen "at the same time" if you use wx.CallAfter. If you're not, there are a bunch of problems that may be triggered by things happening in several threads. Think DC reuse on MS-Windows for instance. Or 2 threads trying to write simultaneously to the same socket (connection to the X server) on Linux...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most wx methods are not thread-safe. Use wx.CallAfter if you want to invoke a wx method from another thread; replace

```
ObjectName.SetLabel(Message)
```

with:

```
wx.CallAfter(ObjectName.SetLabel, Message)
```

**Edit: Some Background Information**

In wx (And in most other UI platforms) all the UI updates get executed in a single thread called main thread (Or UI Thread). This is to make the UI work faster by avoiding the performance hit of thread synchronization.

But the down side of this is that If we write code to update the UI from a different thread the results are undefined. Sometimes it may work, sometimes it may crash, sometimes some other thing may happen. So we should always go to UI thread to do the UI updates. So we use CallAfter function to make UI update function execute in the UI thread.

[UI thread in java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)

[UI thread in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10311/What-s-up-with-BeginInvoke)

Comment: It would be nice to have some background information why it is necessary to do it this way. "WX methods/functions are not thread safe" isn't the complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

The main thing to remember is that you shouldn't update anything in wxPython without using a threadsafe method, such as wx.CallAfter, wx.CallLater or wx.PostEvent. See http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks or http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/ for more information.