# Is there some sort of printing buffer that overflows, when WriteText (AppendText, SetLabel, etc.) continuously in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have some text that goes somewhat continuously on the output (somewhat = every two seconds approx in the real application).

When just `print` into the terminal, everything is ok, no matter how long I keep the running loop.

However, when directing the print to a `wx` frame, the print action itself goes well, no problem here, but if I keep the running loop more than 10-20 cycles, I am no longer able to close the window normally (mouse or Ctrl+F4 in this example, but the same if I construct an explicit Exit event menu). The action in thread stops, but the application hangs -- it can only be closed by the OS (Windows in my case) with a "force close / wait for the program to respond" dialog. Though, it can be closed immediately with Ctrl+C when the terminal window is on focus. It looks like something fills up with too much text and locks the closing process.

Happens with either `WriteText` or `AppendText` on a multiline `wxTextCtrl` window, or with the SetLabel as in the test code below.

In this test, if I close the wx window almost immediately after launch, it closes well. If I keep running the loop longer (or by comment out the two `time.sleep()` lines), then the hang will succeed whenever trying to close the window.

What am I missing here ? (Is there something I have to flush ?)

**edit** Hmm, the issue could be related to "threadsafe method", as described briefly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313169/is-it-still-not-enough-to-simply-use-threads-to-update-gui). Will do some tests in that direction, have to find out the proper usage of each of the `wx.CallAfter`, `wx.CallLater` or `wx.PostEvent`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx
import time
import threading

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.sometext = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "", style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.thread = None
        self.alive = threading.Event()
        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        self.__attach_events()
        self.StartThread()

    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle("test")

    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.sometext, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

    def __attach_events(self):
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        """ stop & close on system window close """
        self.StopThread()
        self.Destroy()

    def StartThread(self):
        """ start the thread """
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.TestThread)
        self.thread.setDaemon(1)
        self.alive.set()
        self.thread.start()

    def StopThread(self):
        """ stop the thread, wait util it is finished """
        if self.thread is not None:
            self.alive.clear()
            self.thread.join()
            self.thread = None

    def TestThread(self):
        """ main thread """
        while self.alive.isSet():
            self.sometext.SetLabel("Hello")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.sometext.SetLabel("Python")
            time.sleep(0.5)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
        frame = TestFrame(None, -1, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        frame.Show(1)
        return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed every SetLabal with AppendtText. I'm don't know why, but SetLabel function don't work correctly for me.

After a few seconds the application will stop working. This is my error output:

```
(python:14099): Pango-CRITICAL **: pango_layout_get_iter: assertion 'PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed
Segmentation fault
```

After that I used CallAfter function http://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter the application started correctly working for me. My version of TestThread:

```
def TestThread(self):
        """ main thread """
        while self.alive.isSet():
            wx.CallAfter(self.sometext.AppendText, "Hello")
            time.sleep(0.5)
        wx.CallAfter(self.sometext.AppendText, "Python") 
        time.sleep(0.5)
        wx.CallAfter(self.sometext.Clear)
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: The `CallAfter` seems the way to go and is working well without further problems in my code. For me `SetLabel` works as it should (and is required as is for my particular requirement), but thanks for pointing out the possible glitch, will do careful tests if/when switching platform.